# Active Dropdown Menus

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, react-bootstrap

I am working on a project where the user has a selection to make. The selection being, *is the member an active member or an inactive member*. If the member is active, the user will select the "Active" selection, if inactive, then the user would select the "Inactive" selection.

[Dropdown Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1WoD.png)

Below is what I am looking for as a result. Is there a way to do this at all?
When, for example "Active" is selected I would like "Select one:" to change and say "Active" instead.

[Activated Dropdown Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbKjE.png)

I hope this makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<h4> Are they active?</h4>
<select>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="active">Active</option>
    <option value="inactive">Inactive</option>
</select>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: When doing this, it gets rid of the "Select one:" which I would like as default.

Comment: Can you edit question, and post code so i can see?

Comment: @PolarRift Edited, with Select your option